# PHP skip entire row from TSV file if certain cell contains X

Tags: php

I have a script that is pulling data from a TSV file and then displaying it to the user in a table format, it also inserts the results into the database after the echo. I was asked if I can add like a #rule where if for instance the $organizer is equal to an organizer listed in a "black list" that whole row is skipped and not displayed on the screen nor is it inserted into the database. I tried a while ago to do a while loop but I broke the existing loop and so I had to revert back. how would I be able to "skip" a row if a value within that row contains a certain value.

```
<?php
  $rs=odbc_exec($conn,$excel);
  while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) 
{
$TimeStamp=odbc_result($rs,"TimeStamp");
$Start_Date=odbc_result($rs,"StartDate");
$TimeStamp = new DateTime($TimeStamp);
$TimeStamp_date = $TimeStamp->format('Y-m-d');
$TimeStamp_time = $TimeStamp->format('h:i:s');

if ($TimeStamp_date == $today)
{
    if ($Start_Date == $today)
    {
    $ID=odbc_result($rs,"ID");
    $StartDate=odbc_result($rs,"StartDate");
    $StartTime=odbc_result($rs,"StartTime");
    $Organizer=odbc_result($rs,"Organizer");
    $MeetingSubject=odbc_result($rs,"MeetingSubject");

    echo '
    <tr>
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $StartDate . '</td>
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $StartTime . '</td>
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $Organizer . '</td>
        <td class="td" valign="top">' . $MeetingSubject . '</td>             </tr> ';
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the part of the code that does the insert?

Comment: if($Organizer == 'Value') continue; // Or whatever field you want to check

Comment: @mjayt - No, I left it out on purpose, the code is a lot more than what I posted

Comment: @Kevin - so if I just use continue, it will skip that line?

Comment: continue will skip the remaining code when used in a loop. The loop will start over on the next record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rest of your insert code is inside of the while, this should work.

```
<?php
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$excel);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs)) 
{

    if($whateverrowvalue != "blacklistvalue") {

        $TimeStamp=odbc_result($rs,"TimeStamp");
        $Start_Date=odbc_result($rs,"StartDate");
        $TimeStamp = new DateTime($TimeStamp);
        $TimeStamp_date = $TimeStamp->format('Y-m-d');
        $TimeStamp_time = $TimeStamp->format('h:i:s');

        if ($TimeStamp_date == $today)
        {

            if ($Start_Date == $today)
            {
            $ID=odbc_result($rs,"ID");
            $StartDate=odbc_result($rs,"StartDate");
            $StartTime=odbc_result($rs,"StartTime");
            $Organizer=odbc_result($rs,"Organizer");
            $MeetingSubject=odbc_result($rs,"MeetingSubject");

            echo '<tr>
            <td class="td" valign="top">' . $StartDate . '</td>
            <td class="td" valign="top">' . $StartTime . '</td>
            <td class="td" valign="top">' . $Organizer . '</td>
            <td class="td" valign="top">' . $MeetingSubject . '</td></tr> ';
            }   

        }

    }

}
?>
```